# JQuery mobile how to prevent the li item to swipe right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using this peace of code https://github.com/ksloan/jquery-mobile-swipe-list that I have modified and its working fine.
However the code has two buttons, right and left. In my project, I only have one in the right side so swipe left to uncover it its ok, but I cannot find how can I eliminate the swipe right since I dont have any button in the left side and it crashes every time it swipe that direction.

Any advice?

Code:

```
  $(function() {
  function prevent_default(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  }
  function disable_scroll() {
  $(document).on('touchmove','#myPostsList .ui-content', prevent_default);
  }
  function enable_scroll() {
  $(document).unbind('touchmove',' #myPostsList .ui-content', prevent_default);
  }
  var x;
  $(document)
  .on('touchstart', '.swipe-delete li > a', function(e) {
  console.log(e.originalEvent.pageX);      
  ///// GET ID OF SELECTED POST AND STORE IN A DIV FOR AJAX /////
  document.getElementById("myPostIDStorage").value = $(this).attr('data-key');

  $('.swipe-delete li > a.open').css('left', '0px').removeClass('open') ;// close em all
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass('open');
  x = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX // anchor point


  })
  .on('touchmove', '.swipe-delete li > a', function(e) {

  var change = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX - x;
  change = Math.min(Math.max(-100, change), 100); // restrict to -100px left, 0px right
  e.currentTarget.style.left = change + 'px';
  if (change < -10) disable_scroll() // disable scroll once we hit 10px horizontal slide
  })
  .on('touchend', '.swipe-delete li > a', function(e) {
  var left = parseInt(e.currentTarget.style.left);

  var new_left;
  if (left < -35) {
  new_left = '-100px';
  } /*else if (left > 35) {
     new_left = '100px'
     } */ else {
  new_left = '0px';
  }
  //e.currentTarget.style.left = new_left
  $(e.currentTarget).animate({left: new_left}, 200)
  enable_scroll();
  });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have all the Original code

All you need to do is change the Maths a little bit

where it says `change = Math.min(Math.max(-100, change), 100);`

change to  `change = Math.min(Math.max(-100, change), 0)`

changing 100 to 0 means 0 pixels of movement from the left to right, so it doesn't move

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/yvjr0zqf/

if you wanted the right side to stop moving reverse the Math but this time 100 is plus number `change = Math.min(Math.max(0, change), 100)`